# Trigger to Fire Upon Insert, INSERT TO Linked Server - "No Transaction is Active"

Tags: sql-server, triggers, replication, linked-server

I have been tasked with linking two servers and upon data being inserted into one table on one server, it should be replicated on the other. I am currently trying to do a test of this in a small table with just the field 'names' (nchar10) and a trigger. The server versions are: Trigger Server - Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and Receiving Server - Microsoft SQL Server 2017. These servers are on different layers.

My problem is that when the trigger fires, I get an error reading:

> The operation could not be performed because SQLNCLI11 for linked
> server xxx was unable to begin a distributed transaction... returned
> message "No transaction is active".

I also think it is worth noting I can manually INSERT Data through the linked server. I only have the problem when it's through the trigger firing.

What I have done:

- Written my Trigger
- Opened Firewalls, added firewall rules to allow incoming and outbound DTC Transactions and opened 1433 Port
- Configured DTC settings
- Configured Link Server Properties
- Tried adding commands to my trigger such as SET XACT_ABORT ON and COMMIT BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION and so on
- Read lots of forums

If anyone wishes to see any settings or scripts I can share these although will block out anything dangerous of course.

I'd also be open to trying this through replication.

[Trigger Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbM87.jpg)

[Linked Server Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SgIk.jpg)

[DTC Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQS0z.jpg)

[Firewall Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvf54.jpg)

[Firewall DTC Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N187T.png)

Comment: Please show your trigger code. Yes replication sounds like a better solution though.

Comment: A little hack i do for mysql linked server is the commit transaction inside the trigger and then do the linked server insert. It allows to avoid the DTS which is *extremely* brittle to setup, but maybe it won't work for you

Comment: I'm big fan of log shipping when it comes to replication. At least for larger data changes, replication wasn't fast enough, but i don't think it will work here, because you are sitting on newer server version at the receiving end :(

Comment: @Charlieface I have added an image to the problem description of the trigger code

Comment: [Please do not show images of code or data, please paste in as text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) Your trigger is fatally flawed anyway, it should handle multiple (or zero) rows in `inserted` by directly using it in the `INSERT` statement, rather than an intermediate variable. What are the linked server settings? What DTC settings do you have, and what have you opened on the firewall? Did you set a static RPC port for it? Are you using the FQDN rather than the IP to connect?

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom @Charlieface. I have added the linked sever settings, DTC settings and firewall settings to the original post. I have port 1433 open and I'm using IP to connect the linked servers. Please let me know if you would like a greater break down of any of these sections and I will add them in :). Appreciate all aids in finding a solution.

Comment: I thought we just said not to post images of code or data? We don't want to see screenshots, never mind poorly taken photos. Enable Distributed Transactions is off, turn it on. Is the firewall settings for the local sie or the remote side? Your trigger code is still fatally flawed as mentioned.